# Autocomplete updated source is not reflecting in Knockout JS

Tags: knockout.js, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have implemented autocomplete in my Knockout JS project using this example

http://cameron-verhelst.be/blog/2014/04/20/knockoutjs-autocomplete/

It is working with my initially populated source data. But later on I have changed the source data on the focus event of my text box on which my autocomplete is applied.But then the auto complete pop up is not populating with updated source data.
by binding is like this

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" style="margin-right:15px;border:0px;" data-bind="value:ConditionData,event:{ focus:assignAutoCompleteArray },autoComplete: {selected:selectedOption, options:options}" placeholder="Key">
```

And I am changing my source by this way

```
 self.assignAutoCompleteArray = function (attribute)
        {
            debugger;
            var attr = attribute;
            var tokenListData = ruleTokenList.map(function (element) {
                return {
                    label: element.label,
                    value: element.value,
                    object: element
                };
            });
            attribute.options = ko.observableArray(tokenListData);
        }
```

My view model is like this

```
var criteria = function () {
        debugger;
        var self = this;
        self.ID = ko.observable();
        self.ConditionData = ko.observable();
        self.Value = ko.observable();
        self.AndOr = ko.observable();
        self.Operator = ko.observable();
        self.Children = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.AndOrList = ko.observableArray([{ key: 'And', value: 'And' }, { key: 'Or', value: 'Or' }]);
        self.operators = ko.observableArray(operatorList);
        self.IsActive = ko.observable();
        self.IsVisibleAddChild = ko.observable(false);
        self.selectedOption = ko.observable('');
        self.options = ruleTokenList.map(function (element) {
            return {
                label: element.label,
                value: element.value,
                object: element
            };
        });
        self.AddChildAttribute = function () {
            var newAttr = new criteria();
            self.Children.push(newAttr);
        }

        self.SaveFilter = function (attribute) {
            self.IsVisibleAddChild(true);
        }

        self.assignAutoCompleteArray = function (attribute)
        {
            debugger;
            var self = this;
            var tokenListData = ruleTokenList.map(function (element) {
                return {
                    label: element.label,
                    value: element.value,
                    object: element
                };
            });

        }
    }
```

What is the issue

Thanks 
Utpal

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing the observableArray instead of just changing out its contents. The one that Knockout had bound is no longer there. You should do

```
attribute.options(tokenListData);
```

to give it new contents.

Comment: if i do this attribute.options(tokenListData); it is giving error options is not a function

Comment: Whatever you're passing to the function needs to already have `options` defined as an `observableArray`. The point is you create the `observableArray` once rather than multiple times.